# How to backap a list with a dates older than a half of Year

Tags: list, development

I want to backup a list when a dates are longer then one half of year. How can I do it on list?
I have got a list:

```
            Contract   |   Worker   |   Day      |   Percent
            ------------------------------------------------
            Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-12 |    1/8
            Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-13 |    1/8
            Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-14 |    1/8
            Con 1      |    Paul    | 2012-10-15 |    1/8
```

And if the date is longer then half of year I want it backup in another list. How Can I do it ? **Please help**

Comment: What do you mean, that after 6 months, the items should be moved to another list or that if the item that is entered has a duration of 6 months or longer it needs to be moved to another list?

Comment: If the time from date now expires 6 month it's date schould be moved to another list, which caled Backup 6 months and more

Comment: Can You Have a sample of code ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements you have a couple options.

If you need to move the item when it's submitted and the date is 6 months or longer, you could use a workflow or event receiver to move it to another list.

If you need to move it after 6 months, you could use Information Rights Management to initiate a workflow to move it to another list.

Comment: Have You got a sample of code how to implement them ?